# how to push data from BlazeDS without receive message from Flex client?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I am using BlazeDS for data-push feature in my Flex application project. From the official tutorial, [Getting started with BlazeDS](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html), it shows messaging example with producer/consumer from API.

but how can I implement server side which doesn't need to be invoke from Flex client, but from within server-side instead. I got some idea but I don't know how to do because I'm a Flex developer, not Java developer, so I think you can help me.

1. In Google, there's a tutorial show about I need to extend `ServiceAdapter` class in Java-side, which extends `Invoke` method. Do I need to extend other class instead of this to do what I want?
2. How to configure the `message-config.xml` to get the result like I describe above?

Comment: Piece of advice, get someone to look over this and correct the grammar.  It is very hard to follow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is test code I wrote and use, at times, to test sending data to our client.  It's a stripped down, bare bones Java example of a ServiceAdapter implementation.  It removes a lot of unnecessary code from the existing examples on the web.  It Compiles, works and I use it often in testing.

```
package your.package.structure.adapter;

import your.package.structure.device.DevicePort;
import flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage;
import flex.messaging.messages.Message;
import flex.messaging.services.MessageService;
import flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter;
import flex.messaging.util.UUIDUtils;

    /**
     * Test service adapter.  Great for testing when you want to JUST SEND AN OBJECT and nothing
     * else.  This class has to stay in the main codebase (instead of test) because, when it's used
     * it needs to be deployed to Tomcat.
     * @author Kevin G
     *
     */

public class TestServiceAdapter extends ServiceAdapter {

    private volatile boolean running;

    private Message createTestMessage() {
        DevicePort objectToSend = new DevicePort("RouterDevice");

        final AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
        msg.setDestination(getClass().getSimpleName() + "Destination");
        msg.setClientId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
        msg.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
        msg.setBody(objectToSend);

        return msg;
    }

    private void sendMessageToClients(Message msg) {
        ((MessageService) getDestination().getService()).pushMessageToClients(msg, false);
    }

    /**
     * @see flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter#start()
     */
    @Override
    public void start(){    
        super.start();

        Thread messageSender = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                running = true;
                while(running){
                    sendMessageToClients(createTestMessage());
                    secondsToSleep(3);
                }
            }
        };

        messageSender.start();        
    }
    /**
     * @see flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter#stop()
     */
    @Override
    public void stop(){
        super.stop();
        running = false;
    }
    /**
     * This method is called when a producer sends a message to the destination. Currently,
     * we don't care when that happens.
     */
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Message message) {
        if (message.getBody().equals("stop")) {
            running = false;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void secondsToSleep(int seconds) {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("TestServiceAdapter Interrupted while sending messages");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        
}
```

You need to set a few properties in tomcat to get this to work.

In `messaging-config.xml`, you need to add an adapter and destination:

Add this line to the existing `<adapters>` tag:

```
 <adapter-definition id="TestServiceAdapter" class="your.package.structure.adapter.TestServiceAdapter"/>
```

Add this destination to that same `messaging-config.xml` file:

```
<destination id="TestServiceAdapterDestination">
        <channels>
            <channel ref="my-streaming-amf"/>
        </channels>
        <adapter ref="TestServiceAdapter"/>
    </destination>
```

Finally, make sure the "my-streaming-amf" channel is defined in `services-config.xml`, as in:

```
<channel-definition id="my-streaming-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/streamingamf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.StreamingAMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
             <!-- you don't need to set all these properties, this is just what we set, included for illustration, only -->
            <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
            <max-streaming-clients>10</max-streaming-clients>
                <server-to-client-heartbeat-millis>5000</server-to-client-heartbeat-millis>
            <user-agent-settings>
                <user-agent match-on="Safari" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="10"/>  
                <user-agent match-on="MSIE" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="15"/> 
                <user-agent match-on="Firefox" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="10"/>
            </user-agent-settings>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

Note that in blazeDS, these two config files (messaging-config.xml and services-config.xml) are located in the following directory:

```
/blazeds/tomcat/webapps/[nameOfYourApp]/WEB-INF/flex/
```

where `[nameOfYourApp]` is the directory your webapp lives in.

I hope all that helps!

-kg

Comment: This is awesome. Would it be possible to also recieve the message you send in that same class?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to push messages from the server to the client? In this case take a look in the BlazeDS samples. There is a sample in a folder called traderdesktop. The piece of code which is sending the messages is below:

```
MessageBroker msgBroker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);

AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();

msg.setDestination(yourdestination);

msg.setClientId(clientID);

msg.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());

msg.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

msg.setBody("dummy");

msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Comel. What is the clientID I need to specify? or where could I get it from?

Comment: From the same sample: String clientID = UUIDUtils.createUUID();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the url to the stream at runtime do the following:

```
//assumes _consumer is an instance variable mx.messaging.Consumer
var channelSet:ChannelSet = new ChannelSet();
//change {server.name}:{server.port} to the end point you wanna hit
var ep:String = "http://{server.name}:{server.port}/messagebroker/streamingamf";
var channel:StreamingAMFChannel = new StreamingAMFChannel("my-streaming-amf", ep);
channelSet.addChannel(channel);

_consumer = new Consumer();
_consumer.channelSet = channelSet;
_consumer.destination = "TestServiceAdapterDestination";
_consumer.subscribe(); 
_consumer.addEventListener(MessageEvent.MESSAGE, onMsg); 
_consumer.addEventListener(MessageFaultEvent.FAULT, faultHandler);
```

Just a heads up.  This took some head banging to get going.  I hope it helps someone.