# How to receive push data from blazeds in flex 4

Tags: xml, flex4, push, blazeds

I am trying to receive push data from blazeds. I found how to send push data from blazeds without any message from client in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872742/how-to-push-data-from-blazeds-without-recieve-message-from-flex-client). Now I don't know how to know from flex that data has been sent from server and how to receive that data . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To recieve messages from the link that you shared above there are couple of things that you need to do.

1. You need to declare a Consumer as shown below that will consume messages from the defined channel.
2. Note that I set the `message` property to an event handler show below

   ```
   private function onMsg(event:MessageEvent):void
   {
       trace("Signal Arrives : "+event.message.body);

       //var signal:SignalProcessor = new SignalProcessor ();
       //signal.processMessage(event.message.body);
   }
   ```
3. Create a method that will be called at creationComplete of your application such as one defined below

   private function suscribeForMessages():void
   {
   //Where consumer is the Id of the Consumer mxml tag.
   //You need the selector only if you want your client to selectively recieve messages from
   //the adapter.
   consumer.selector = "filterID IN('"+userIdVariable+"')";
   consumer.subscribe();
   }

The 3 steps above should get you up and bouncing. Good luck.