# How to set listener into Flex datagrid using java as back-end

Tags: java, apache-flex, datagrid

I am using Java as back-end. From server side i created simple service that retrieves data from the database. From Flex side i created simple datagrid and filled it using my java service. Everything works perfectly but i want to set something like listener to datagrid that when new data will be entered to database my flex datagrid automatically will be refreshing. I think that i need somethings from server side that will be waiting from new data and when it appears then should somehow notify flex. It is possible to do that ?

Comment: If you want your server to tell the Flex UI tha something has changed with the data; then you'll need to use a server-side software that supports push notifications; such as LiveCycle or GraniteDS.

Comment: I use BlazeDS to transfer data from Java to Flex but i still don't know how to do this dynamically without button like refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to say I haven't said.  You need to use a server-side software that supports push notifications; such as LiveCycle or GraniteDS.  I do not believe that BlazeDS supports that.  ( The functionality was not added to BlazeDS because Adobe wanted to keep some advanced functionality in LiveCycle to entice enterprise customers to get on board )

Comment: Push notifications it is what i need. Thank you for a tip :)

Comment: @Reboog711 BlazeDS supports push-messaging thats why there's messaging-config.xml. I've used that.

Answer (score 0):

Just look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872742/how-to-push-data-from-blazeds-without-recieve-message-from-flex-client) thread on Stack Overflow. BlazeDS offers push-notification which can solve your problem of sending update to client without getting request for the same.

The BlazeDS's sample chat application uses push notifications. You can check for the same at your BlazeDS deployment url [BlazeDS root url]/samples/runtimeconfig-messaging/index.html